# Postgresql 13 - fire trigger once for group records

Tags: postgresql

I have table:

```
| id |depth| depth_ex| b_id|
|----|-----|---------|-----|
|  1 |   0 |   0.00  |  1  |
|  2 |   1 |   1.00  |  1  |
|  3 |   2 |   3.00  |  1  |
| 15 |   3 |   6.00  |  1  |
|  6 |  35 |  41.00  |  1  |
| 12 | 100 | 141.00  |  1  |
|  9 |   0 |   0.00  |  2  |
| 10 |  20 |  20.00  |  2  |
| 11 |  40 |  60.00  |  2  |
```

For this table, i created TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION depth_ex() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'; 

    UPDATE a
      SET depth_ex = sub.new_depth
    FROM (
        SELECT
             id,
            SUM(depth) OVER (ORDER BY depth ASC) AS new_depth
        FROM
            a
        WHERE b_id = NEW.b_id
    ) sub
    WHERE a.id = sub.id;
 
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
 
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER depth_ex_trig
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF depth ON a
   DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE depth_ex();
```

After:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE a SET depth = 6 where id = 2;
UPDATE a SET depth = 10 where id = 3;
UPDATE a SET depth = 15 where id = 15;
COMMIT;
```

I expected to see !!!!!!!! only one, but i saw three times.

```
NOTICE:  !!!!!!!!
NOTICE:  !!!!!!!!
NOTICE:  !!!!!!!!
COMMIT

Query returned successfully in 31 msec.
```

How to rewrite procedure or trigger to see NOTICE:  !!!!!!!! only once, or fire trigger for group of record one ( with the same b_id) ?

Regards

Comment: I do not believe you can get what you want. Triggers, deferred or not, fire on DML statements not on transactions. While your 3 inserts are contained within a *single transaction* there are *still 3 complete statements*.

Comment: OK, How to handle the situation when there are 100,000 UPDATES in one transaction and then !!!!!!!! will show up 100 000 times. And it is enough if trigger executes once , at the end of transaction, and displays !!!!! only once. I i have 3 Updates it is not problem, I 1000 0000, it is.

Comment: Then you need to come up with a non trigger bases solution. Perhaps the community con help there if you explain the issue you are trying to resolve; not how to redefine Postgres. BTW I have never considered 100K to be all that many nor do I have the compelling need to track it.

Comment: You could try a statement trigger and use a single `update` statement to set the 3 values.